# python - contents of file vanish after end of program

Tags: python, file

I have got a function which is bound to a key
This function writes something into a file, as it should:

```
def saveGame():
from modules.logic import game
from modules.logic.player import Player
from modules.logic.light import Light
filename = str(time.time())
data = open("myData", "a")
lis1 = []
if (len(game.active_entities)>0):
        for key in game.active_entities:
            if (not isinstance(game.active_entities, Light)):
                if(not isinstance ( game.active_entities, Light)):
                        ent = game.active_entities[key]
                        ent2 = ent.networknew()
                        lis1.append(ent2) 
        lis1.insert(0, game.get_player().networknew())
        lis1.insert(0,game.seed)
        saved = open(filename, "w")          
        pickle.dump( lis1,saved, 2)
        try:
            data.write(filename+"\n")
        except Exception as e:
            print e
```

savegame is called when a certain key is pressed. It creates a new file, saves something in it (what is saved is not important here) and then saves the name of the new file in yet another file.

However, when I end and restart the program, the second file is empty, even so, as long as the program is still running, it has the right contents.
I would like to still have the contents after the program is close. Is that possible?
How?

To your question:

I start my game by opening a Window:

```
class StartWindow:

def __init__(self):


    data = open("myData", "w")
    data.close()
    data = open ("myData", "rb")
    self.master = Tk()       
    if (not data.readline()== ""):
        optsdumped = data.readlines()[0]
        print optsdumped
        opts = cPickle.loads(optsdumped)
        print opts
        variable = StringVar(self.master)
        variable.set("one") # default value
        self.w = OptionMenu(self.master, variable, "one", "two", "three").grid(row = 8, sticky = W)
        #self.w.grid(row = 7, sticky = W)
        print "optionmenu"
    self.l0 =Label (self.master,fg = "blue", text = "W=jump", bg = "magenta", font = ("comic sans ms", 20, "bold")).grid(row=0, sticky = W)
    self.l1=Label (self.master,fg = "blue", text = "A=left",bg = "magenta",font = ("comic sans ms", 20, "bold")).grid(row = 1, sticky = W)
    self.l2=Label(self.master,fg = "blue", text = "D=Duck", bg = "magenta",font = ("comic sans ms", 20, "bold")).grid(row=2, sticky = W )
    self.l3=Label(self.master,fg = "blue", text = "Mouse = Shoot", bg = "magenta",font = ("comic sans ms", 20, "bold")).grid(row=3, sticky = W)
    self.l4=Label(self.master,fg = "blue", text = "S=Duck", bg = "magenta",font = ("comic sans ms", 20, "bold")).grid(row=4, sticky = W)
    self.l5=Label(self.master,fg = "blue", text="Seed:", bg = "magenta",font = ("comic sans ms", 20, "bold")).grid(row=5, sticky = W)
    self.master.minsize(50, 50)
    self.master.weight = 2
    self.master.title("Fluffocalypse")
    print self.master.configure(bg = "magenta")
    self.e1 = Entry(self.master)
    self.e1.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky = W)
    self.b1 =Button(self.master, text = "Start", command = self.startGameNormally).grid(row = 6, sticky = W)
    self.b2 = Button(self.master, text = "alten Spielstand laden", command =self.loadOldGame).grid(row = 7, sticky = W)
    mainloop()
```

Well, the window is there alright, but somehow the ifclause is never fulfilled, and myData is clearly empty, even if I open it by hand. Why is that?

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code sample, with Python it's really not possible to tell what it's supposed to be if it appears broken.

Comment: Also consider simplifying your code sample by reducing it to a test case that manifests the same problem you're having using dummy data and without referring to `import`ed code that's neither relevant nor known.

Comment: I am using Aptana which usually tells me if it is not happy with the indentation - it does not with my sample, so I do not see any mistakes.

Comment: You would do well by looking at your actual post. It's obviously busted (the first line after `def saveGame():` isn't indented, same for your second sample after `class StartWindow:`), so at least *some* of the indentation from your IDE didn't transfer correctly to the SO question, which is why I'm wondering exactly what did and what didn't.

Comment: That's probably because you thought indenting the first line of the code block is enough. It is not.

Comment: Also, the thrust of my second comment was that you should show us **less** code, not **more**. This makes it harder to find the cause of your problem amongst all the irrelevant clutter.

Comment: By the way, Python doesn't require parentheses in `if`. And `not data.readline()== ""` looks very wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening the file with the `w` flag every time you run your program. This destroys data saved by the previous run. Use append mode.

Answer (score 2):

You never close the file explicitly, so it is possible its contents are never actually written. You need either an explicit `saved.close()` or preferably use the context manager, for example:

```
with open(filename, "w") as saved: 
    pickle.dump( lis1,saved, 2)
    try:
        data.write(filename+"\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

It is a good idea to do the same for `data` even though it's opened only for reading.

Comment: actually the problem is not saved - all the data I want to are in there and stay there (maybe because I use dump instead of write?). They do not, however, stay in data. I DID try to close data right after putting that question here - to know avail. If I use the key the function is bound to, then open myData while the program is still running, the content is correct. As soon as I close the program, the file myData remains, yet its content simply vanishes.

Comment: @newnewbie if you tried to close the file and that didn't help then show the code that should work but doesn't.

Comment: I just realised that the contents do not vanish when I close the old program but when I start it anew. I edit my question according to your question in a few seconds.

Comment: @newnewbie You open `data` with `w` which truncates it and expect it to have content?